# How can I get html5 tags to work with older versions of IE?

Tags: html

I've tried using `<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>` but still does not work. please help.

thanks

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is "You can't". And you should say which older version of IE you had in mind.

Comment: Can you add more detail?  What doesn't work? What IE version?

Comment: Yes, the main question here is what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, it's more a matter of what you mean by "not working."

The HTML5Shim is a tool to get IE to recognize the new HTML5 elements like <nav>, <section>, <article> and so on. So that you can use CSS and JavaScript on those elements like you would a <div> tag.

But the Shim won't make the <video> or <audio> tag suddenly start playing video or audio files. Nor will it allow you to do geolocation or pull up calendars for the <input type="date"> field.

If you have to write pages for IE8 and lower, you should check out http://caniuse.com/ to see what aspects of HTML5 are supported by older versions of IE. You might be surprised that it does support some things. And for other options, you should consider making them enhancements to your pages rather than requirements.